# Xamarin, C#, when using AndroidX, how do you get your activity's default FragmentManager to use the AndroidX version not the old one?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, androidx, fragmentmanager

I have AndroidX in my Xamarin Android project.  In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/managing-fragments, the article says each activity has it's own FragmentManager and you use "this." to reference it.
But, when I do the following:

```
var fragmentTransaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();  // using Android.App. the deprecated version
```

I can see the "this." references the obsolete one -- how do you force an activity to automatically include the new AndroidX version ?

Comment: You can check the class that your activity implement. If it implements the AppCompatActivity and the Target Android version is higher than 9, the code 'AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = this.SupportFragmentManager' will work correctly.Because the code 'this.SupportFragmentManager' uses the package Android.Support.V4.App in high version and use the package AndroidX.Fragment.App in low version such as Android 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even the latest preview of VS2022 still defaults to using the deprecated Android.App.Fragment when creating a Fragment when using the standard template for adding a new item. So you immediately end up with the wrong Fragment.

Just as Fragment should derive from AndroidX.Fragment.App, so should FragmentManager, therefore you need AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager

e.g.
AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = this.SupportFragmentManager;

or if you require from with a static method you can pass the Activity as a parameter to the method and use it like the following

AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = activity.SupportFragmentManager;

Basically, you really just need to get your using statements right making sure you are using AndroidX versions and then be aware of the different syntax if obtaining the FragmentManager from a fragment or an Activity.

You may also want to consider changing the handling of fragments to use the NavigationComponent which basically eliminates the need for directly using the FragmentManager.

Comment: The statement, AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = this.SupportFragmentManager;, gives me "cannot implicitly convert" and this statement, AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = activity.SupportFragmentManager;, "an object reference is required" errors.   Can you please show how to do this more in a more exact way ?

Comment: What a shambles

Answer (score 0):

My example assumes you are passing the Activity as a parameter to a static function.

What happens if say in your MainActivity at the end of the OnCreate you just add the following line.

AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = this.SupportFragmentManager;

You can write it without the "this" if you prefer, the editor will also suggest that you remove the "this" as it is unnecessary for "this" is already the Activity if you are in the MainActivity. The "this" will be greyed out and the editor will state this line can be simplified.

The reason you need the full AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager and not just FragmentManager is that you probably also have using Andriod.App in your using statements at the top of your MainActivity. You don't want the old Android.App.FragmentManager, therefore you have to use the full namespace.

If you are trying to get the fragment manager from inside a Fragment then you would need the following

AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.

Comment: If, at the end of my Oncreate, I add this code, as you mention, AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm = this.SupportFragmentManager;, I get:  
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager' to 'AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager' GPSSatellite5 C:\code\Xamarin\GPSSatellite6\GPSSatellite5\MapActivity.cs.   Btw, I have min version as 10 and Target as 11.  What do you get when trying ?

Comment: You are trying to use both the Xamarin.Android.Support libraries and the Xamarin.AndroidX libraries at the same time. Android.Support libs are all deprecated and have been since Android10. You need to migrate all those libraries to the Xamarin.AndroidX libs.  I never used it, but there is an AndroidX migration package that is meant to help with the migration - maybe you could look at that.